# How do I remove warning "Warning: Prop `style` did not match" when I import Image component in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

Friends when importing an image with the Image component of nextjs I get the following warning:

> Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "display: block;
> max-width: 100%; width: initial; height: initial; background: none;
> opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
> --darkreader-inline-bgimage:none; --darkreader-inline-bgcolor: initial; --darkreader-inline-border-top: initial;
> --darkreader-inline-border-right: initial; --darkreader-inline-border-bottom: initial; --darkreader-inline-border-left: initial;" Client: "display:block;max-width:100%;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0"
> at img at span at span at Image
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:50:20)
> at LoadableImpl
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/loadable.js:142:5)
> at a at LinkComponent
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:108:19)
> at div at header at div at Header at div at Layout
> (webpack-internal:///./components/Layout.js:15:23) at div at Home at
> MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:18:24) at ErrorBoundary
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:20742)
> at ReactDevOverlay
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:23635)
> at Container
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:111:5)
> at AppContainer
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:300:24)
> at Root
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:508:25)

I have already tried importing dynamically, adding a .babelrc file and placing a loader on the component and nothing.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-next": "^1.4.0",
    "next": "12.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.0"
  }
```

code:

```
import Image from "next/image"
    import Link from "next/link";
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
    // const Images = dynamic(() => import('next/image'));
    
    import styles from "../styles/Header.module.css";
    
    const Header = () => {
    
      return (
        <div>
          <header className={styles.header}>
            <div className={`container ${styles.menuLogo}`}>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>
                  <Image
                    src="/blog-img.svg"
                    width={190}
                    height={120}
                    alt="logo"
                  />
                </a>
              </Link>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
   export default Header;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using `<a>` tag within a `<Link>`?

Comment: Piyush Satija I put the <a> tag to avoid this error Warning: function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this reference will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the dark reader extension, which had it activated and changed the color of the web page and this raised the alarm: since the representation on the server is not the same on the client. If the extension is deactivated, the error is eliminated.

It has nothing to do with the Image component of nextjs.

more information: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40648

Comment: wow thank you so much.  I had a similar extension and removing it fixed the problem!